How to use $ref to set conditions on objects of sub schemas using json schema draft 2020-12 in a spring boot project?
I'm trying to do json schema validation in spring boot 3.3.3, in resources folder I have put the schemas main.json, sub1.json and sub2.json. I’m using $ref to refer other schema objects from main schema and I want to set a field condition in sub2 based on a value of property from sub1, but I’m getting required field missing always when validating even when value is different. Added expected and obtained result at the end with same results.
Dependency used for schema validation:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.networknt</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>

Bean to load schemas:
@Bean
public JsonSchema jsonSchema() {
    return JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V202012)
        .getSchema(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(“/main.json”));
}

Controller method:
@Autowired
private JsonSchema jsonSchema;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@PostMapping("/validate")
public void validate(@RequestBody RequestDto request) {
    JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.valueToTree(request);
    Set<ValidationMessage> validationMessages = jsonSchema.validate(jsonNode);
    
    if (!validationMessages.isEmpty()) {
        throw new JsonSchemaValidationException(validationMessages);
    }
    log.info("Validation Passed");
}

main.json:
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "title": "ResponsePayload",
    "description": "Payload object response",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "objectA": {
            "$ref": "classpath:/sub1.json"
        },
        "objectB": {
            "$ref": "classpath:/sub2.json"
        },
        "objectC": {
            "$ref": "classpath:/sub3.json"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "objectA",
        "objectB"
    ]
}

sub1.json:
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "title": "Sub1Payload",
    "description": "Sub payload 1",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "number": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "type-emp-land": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "location": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "area": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "name",
        "number",
        "type-emp-land"
    ]
}

sub2.json:
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "title": "Sub2Payload",
    "description": "Sub payload 2",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "area": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "radius": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "cm": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "km": {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            }
        },
        "type-emp-land-location": {
            "$ref": "classpath:/sub1.json#/properties/type-emp-land/properties/location"
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "location",
        "area"
    ],
    "allOf": [
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "type-emp-land-location": {
                        "const": "InsideNothingHall"
                    }
                }
            },
            "then": {
                "required": [
                    "radius"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

Input 1:
{
    "objectA": {
        "name": "Wired",
        "number": 1234,
        "type-emp-land": {
            "location": "InsideNothingHall",
            "area": "Inside square"
        }
    },
    "objectB": {
        "location": "Mid",
        "area": "50 cm"
    }
}

Expected:
JsonSchemaValidationException with required field 'radius' missing message.

Output:
 JsonSchemaValidationException with required field 'radius' missing message

Input 2:
{
    "objectA": {
        "name": "Wired",
        "number": 1234,
        "type-emp-land": {
            "location": "OutTown",
            "area": "Inside square"
        }
    },
    "objectB": {
        "location": "Mid",
        "area": "50 cm"
    }
}

Expected:
Validation Passed - log.
Output:
JsonSchemaValidationException with required field 'radius' missing message

For both the cases I’m getting the same exception, but in case of input2 no exception should occur.
What am I missing here?

Your approach won't work. Before we get into an approach that will work, let's understand why the current approach behaves the way it does.
This is your if schema.
{
  "properties": {
    "type-emp-land-location": {
      "const": "InsideNothingHall"
    }
  }
}

The value (in both inputs) that's being evaluated is,
{
  "location": "Mid",
  "area": "50 cm"
}

Because the property "type-emp-land-location" doesn't exist in the value, this schema passes validation. Therefore, the then schema gets evaluated which gives you the error you see.
You can fix the if schema by adding "required": ["type-emp-land-location"]. That should make both inputs pass validation and it should now be clear that your attempt to link to "type-emp-land" using "type-emp-land-location" doesn't do what you think it does.
if/thens need to be at a level high enough in the JSON tree to address all values they need to validate. In this case, that means your if/then needs to be in the main.json schema. There's no clever way around that. It would look something like this,
"if": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "objectA": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type-emp-land": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "location": { "const": "InsideNothingHall" }
          },
          "required": ["location"]
        }
      },
      "required": ["type-emp-land"]
    }
  },
  "required": ["objectA"]
},
"then": {
  "properties": {
    "objectB": {
      "required": ["radius"]
    }
  }
}

